# Vetor recebendo uma função que retorna inteiros

Tags: java, array, funções

Galera, Eu tenho algumas dúvidas sobre vetores e funções.

```
public class teste{

/*Função que retorna um vetor de inteiros com números aleatórios*/

public static int [] vetorFuncao(){

 int numerosAleatorios [] = new int[10];

 for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

     numerosAleatorios[i] = ( (int) (Math.random()*10) )+1;
    }   

    return numerosAleatorios;

}

/*Principal*/

public static void main(String[]args){

int [] vetor = vetorFuncao();

     }

}
```

Eu sei que para criar um vetor deve-se informar a quantidade de posições. 
Ex: `int [] vetor = new int [10];`

No entanto, `int [] vetor = vetorFuncao();` não precisa especificar a quantidade de posição, pois a quantidade de posições será igual a quantidade de posições do  `vetorFuncao();`

Por que não precisa especificar a quantidade de posições do vetor `int [] vetor = vetorFuncao()` quando eu crio um vetor que recebe uma determinada função que retorna um vetor de inteiros.

`int [ ] vetor = new int [x];` Precisa especificar `x`;

`int [] vetor = vetorFuncao();` Não precisa especificar, pois `vetor.lenght` será igual à `vetorFuncao();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos reorganizar o seu código:

```
public class Teste {

    public static int[] vetorFuncao() {

        int[] numerosAleatorios = new int[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            numerosAleatorios[i] = ((int) (Math.random() * 10)) + 1;
        }

        return numerosAleatorios;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] vetor = vetorFuncao();
    }
}
```

Primeiro, preste atenção no `new`. Essa palavra chave diz que algo vai ser criado. Quando você faz um `new int[10]` você está criando um array com 10 posições. A parte do `numerosAleatorios =` diz que esse array vai ser atribuído à variável `numerosAleatorios`, que é do tipo `int[]`. Assim sendo, a linha `int[] numerosAleatorios = new int[10];` faz isso:

- Declara uma variável do tipo `int[]` chamada `numerosAleatorios`.
- Cria um array de inteiro com 10 posições.
- Atribui esse array recém-criado à variável `numerosAleatorios`.

Mais abaixo, ainda dentro do método `vetorFuncao()` você tem o `return numerosAleatorios;`. Essa instrução devolve o array `numerosAleatorios` como resultado ao método que o chamou.

Dentro do método `main(String[])`, quando você chama `vetorFuncao()`, você está invocando o método `vetorFuncao()`. O método `vetorFuncao()` irá retornar o array que ele criou como resultado. Quando você tem o `int[] vetor = vetorFuncao();`, esse array que é criado dentro de `vetorFuncao()` será atribuído à variável `vetor`. O `main` não criará por si só nenhum array, ele apenas receberá o array que `vetorFuncao()` se encarregou de criar.

Neste caso, o `main` está confiando ao método `vetorFuncao()` a criação do array, inclusive o seu tamanho. Dentro do `vetorFuncao()`, o tamanho está definido como 10, e é esse array que será devolvido. Se você quiser definir o tamanho no `main`, basta usar um parâmetro:

```
public class Teste {

    public static int[] vetorFuncao(int tamanho) {

        int[] numerosAleatorios = new int[tamanho];

        for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
            numerosAleatorios[i] = ((int) (Math.random() * 10)) + 1;
        }

        return numerosAleatorios;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] vetor = vetorFuncao(10);
    }
}
```

Neste caso, o método `vetorFuncao` "pede" para quem for utilizá-lo o tamanho do array que vai ser criado, e esse tamanho é diretamente repassado ao `new`. O `main` informa esse valor como 10 no parâmetro de `vetorFuncao`.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @RaphaelRibeiro Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema, marque-a como aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela. Isso também marcará a sua pergunta como solucionada/resolvida. Caso ainda não esteja satisfeito e lhe restem dúvidas ou objeções, sinta-se livre para comentar. Se preferir marcar a outra resposta, sinta-se a vontade, embora você só possa escolher uma delas como aceita.

Answer (score 0):

Há uma "sutil" diferença entre as duas formas que você usou;

A primeira foi a criação de um vetor, nesse momento, para a criação, é necessário declarar a quantidade de posições, pois será um vetor inicial com todas as suas posições vazias, e para isso é necessário indicar quantas serão.

```
int[] vetor = new int[10];
```

Já na segunda forma, que é atribuição, não é necessário pois a variável somente receberá o valor retornado por uma função, não necessitando assim ser definida seu tamanho, pois como é o retorno de algo, o tamanho será definido com base na quantidade retornada pela função;

Um é **inicialização** de vetor, e no outro é **atribuição**.

Comment: Muito obrigado!